# How to reset a singleton in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, singleton

The singleton contains plenty of variables.

How to quickly reset the variables to nil or 0 ?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no such method for that you need to make your own method which resets all and call that method when required.

Comment: @Amit Singh you can, in fact write a method that takes all Ivars and sets them to `0`. The Objective-C runtime allows for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write a method in the singleton that does it for you.

Comment: What does this mean in terms of releasing/deallocating objects that might be part of the singleton, like a dictionary?